# How can I get this to work on the other files too while it's still working on another one?

Tags: c#

I've been trying to get a mp3 converter working with the use of a NuGet package. Right now I'm trying to get "multithreading" to work, so that it converts multiple files at the same time and not just one at a time.

```
private void convert()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < file_paths.Length; i++)
    {
        FFMpeg.Convert2Mp3(file_paths[i], $"output\\{(string)file_names[i]}.mp3");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Parallel.For`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for) for this:

```
var parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = MAX_NUMBER_OF_PARALLEL_FILES
};

Parallel.For(0, file_paths.Length, parallelOptions, i =>
{
    FFMpeg.Convert2Mp3(file_paths[i], $"output\\{file_names[i]}.mp3");
});
```

Comment: thanks, was trying a Parallel.For loop before but couldn't find examples simple enough for me to understand. it's working now, thanks :)